# Downloading via OTA in iOS8 doesn't cause browser to minimize

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ota

As we know there is possibility to install an app via OTA (itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://myWebsite/myApp/myApp.plist)
Prior to iOS8 (iOS6/iOS7), even using an iframe that's source was itms-services://, was opening a blank page in safari mobile but at least after prompting to install an app, the browser was automatically minimized and the downloading indicator was shown.

Now it's not even doing that! I have a button that creates a new frame and as a src parameter it puts itms-services url. What happens is, it zooms out current page and asks if to install the app. If I confirm, it stays at such position (with half zoom-out tab/page) and begins installation in the background. This looks terrible.

Ref image:

[image]

Also I tried to use itms-services as an URL in a webclip, however in this case it'll open blank white page, ask if to install and if you decline it will just keep the white/blank page opened and if you confirm it'll begin installation on the springboard but all what user sees is still white screen.

Any alternatives to that?
How can I minimize browser after trying to install the application? I can't even notice the user on the page to click home button because the page/tab is zoomed out. If I use `<a href="itms...">`, it'll open blank page which is even worse.